# Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments. : WP7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I know this is a known issue. Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone's emulator has stopped working all of sudden.

Hint: It was working fine before i started deploying apps to My Nokia Lumia. After then it was failing to start. Could that be a reason for error?

Error it throws:

`Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments.`

Any workaround?!

TIA.

Edit: Sorry, I am using VS 2010 only.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone development is not supported in VS 11. The windows phone development team released a statement saying that they were working on addressing the issue, but for now Win7/VS2010 should be used for WP7 development.

There have been some hacks going around to make the emulator work, but I would recommend staying away from them, since some users have been experiencing windows crashes.

If you're working on Windows 8, then you should still be able to deploy to your phone and debug your code on the phone. If you're running Windows 7 then use VS 2010 and everything should work.

Comment: I am developing an app, i can deploy and test it on my phone, but i m not able to take snapshot of my app. Is there any way i can get snapshots of my app?

Comment: There is no "legit" way of taking a screenshot on the phone. There have been various XDA application that do this, but it shouldn't be necessary as the emulator supports screen shots.

Comment: but as i said, emulator stopped working after i deployed it on phone. i don't know the exact reason, i can't make it run after few hours of googling.

Comment: You can take screen shots from the phone using ScreenCapturer tool available for download

Comment: What is this link supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this can be tracked down the the nvidia dll nvwgf2um.dll.  Look in event viewer for an XDE crash.

To get around this I just copied an older version into the XDE application folder and bingo, worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a laptop with integrated and hardware accelerated graphics.
The solution for the crashes was to use only integrated Intel graphics. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My Windows 7 did not come with Windows Media Player. When I installed the player the problem was solved :-)

link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546

Comment: i wonder how installing a media player can solve this problem.
by the way, i formatted pc (not because of emulator problem of course) installed wp7 sdk and emulator started working again! there is something wrong!