# Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, exception

Hi want to develop a windows phone application. I have vs2010 ultimate installed in my pc. I downloaded Windows Phone 7 SDK and started developing an application. But when i run the app from VS I'm getting following error:

> Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue got resolved when i downloaded and installed Media Format Feature Pack for Windows 7 N with Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are few reasons that prevent to connect with emulator as:

1. Less RAM then required so I boost it.
2. There may exists previous tools builds installed + uninstalled, you’ll have to manually delete the folder `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Phone Tools` in order to get the emulator to work again.
3. If the same thing occur when you create a blank application and run it, then hopefully it's just a faulty installation.

Restart the solution and after that if it does not work then In the mean time a developer seems to have found a workaround, see here at *Windows Phone 7 Forum* - [Emulator won't launch; installation problem?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/fde4c415-44c5-4837-b1cd-e09727a75b92/)

> If you're having problem using an app but trying to develop one. If
>   that is the case, I suggest you go the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/) for additional
>   help. This is where all the Windows Phone developers go for free
>   resources, training and help.

Ref:
[Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments. : WP7 Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705234/connection-failed-because-of-invalid-command-line-arguments-wp7-emulator)
[Connecting to Windows Phone 7 Emulator](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/187602.aspx/1)